# Retrieve records from Active Directory using data structure algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, binary-tree, active-directory-group

I need to fetch active directory records and insert in SQL database. There are approximately 10,000 records. I have used this code:

```
List<ADUser> users = new List<ADUser>();

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xyz.com");
ADUser userToAdd = null;

IList<string> dict = new List<string>();               

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
search.PageSize = 1000;

foreach (SearchResult result in search.FindAll())
{
    DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

    if (user != null && user.Properties["displayName"].Value!=null)
    {
        userToAdd = new ADUser
                    {
                        FullName = Convert.ToString(user.Properties["displayName"].Value),
                        LanId = Convert.ToString(user.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value)
                    };

        users.Add(userToAdd);
    }
}
```

How can I optimize the above code in terms of speed and space complexity? Can I use traversal in binary tree as Active Directory structure looks similar to binary tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list returned by [`DirectorySearcher.FindAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall) is just a list. So you can't traverse it any better than you already are.

To optimize this, don't use `GetDirectoryEntry()`. That is doing two things:

1. Making another network request to AD that is unnecessary since the search can return any attributes you want, and
2. Taking up memory since all those `DirectoryEntry` objects will stay in memory until you call `Dispose()` or the GC has time to run (which it won't till your loop finally ends).

First, add `displayName` to your `PropertiesToLoad` to make sure that gets returned too. Then you can access each property by using `result.Properties[propertyName][0]`. Used this way, *every* property is returned as an array, even if it is a single-value attribute in AD, hence you need the `[0]`.

Also, if your app is staying open after this search completes, make sure you call `Dispose()` on the `SearchResultCollection` that comes out of `FindAll()`. In the documentation for `FindAll()`, [the "Remarks" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) indicates you could have a memory leak if you don't. Or you can just put it in a `using` block:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
search.PageSize = 1000;
using (SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        if (result.Properties["displayName"][0] != null) {
            userToAdd = new ADUser {
                FullName = (string) result.Properties["displayName"][0],
                LanId = (string) result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]
            };

            users.Add(userToAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to traverse the active directory ? using recursion or binary any other algorithm?.

Comment: Of course, but it would be slower than this method you're already using. To optimize speed, you need to keep the number of network requests down. This search you're doing will get 1000 accounts at a time. If you try to traverse AD through the tree, you can only get the contents of 1 OU at a time, so you'll end up doing more network requests than you would with this search.

Comment: Thank you it worked ...now its fetching the 5000 records in 1.3 seconds.